# Day and month reverse during MVC model binding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a strange problem seems to only happens in the test W2k12 server for my ASP MVC3 app.

My development environment is MVC3/.NET4.0/Win7/VS2010.  The deployment server is W2k12 running .NET 4.5

In my model, my datetime fields are generally defined as:

```
[DisplayName("From (dd/mm/yyyy)")]
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? InputDateTime { get; set; }
```

In my view, it just render out the date as string within a text box (i.e. without datepicker)

In my development box (Win7 professional), if I type day and month **only** (for example: dd/mm), and then click the Save/Submit button, it calls the JQuery .serialize() method and pass on to the controller's AJAX method.  It maps to  date field correctly in the dd/mm/yyyy format (and add the current year automatically).  It also saves to DB as a date field no problem.

It is important to note that the form data is serialized and not passed as Json string (not stringified), using $.ajax (jQuery 1.7.x)

If I type 'dd/mm/yyyy' in the text box, it also saves correctly.

However, my problem starts after the program has been deployed to the W2K12 server (running under .NET 4.5):

if I type only dd/mm (e.g. 10/04), the day and month swap and saves as mm/dd (plus the current year, thus mm/dd/yyyy).  The 'swapping' does not occur on the jQyery.serializer but it only passes on to the MVC controller as a string.

If I type the full dd/mm/yyyy, the month and date don't swap

I check the regional and date format (short/long date) on the W2k12 they all seem OK (Australia region, dd/mm/yyyy format) and identical to my W7 box.

Can someone shed some lights on that? Please ask if you require more information.

p.s. the following is already in web.config file:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU" />
```

Comment: I have a very similar issue, it's working fine on local, but have issues after deployed to Azure.

Answer (score 3):

I just fixed my similar issue by adding

`<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB"/>`

into system.web node in web.config

Comment: but i have something similar on mind already (refer to my question) and the same problem still happens.

Comment: @WML I found that it's fixed for desktop browsers. But when on mobile like iOS devices, it still has the issue